# Thumbnails using twitter bootstrap not vertically aligned

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails

Here's my sample output:

[image]

Here's my `html` code on it:

```
<div class="products">
<ul class="thumbnails">'
    <li>
        <div>'.$item->ASIN.'</div>
        <div><img src="'.$item->SmallImage->URL.'" alt=""></div>
        <div>'.$item->ItemAttributes->Title.'</div>
        <div>'.$item->ItemAttributes->ProductGroup.'</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And here's my `css` code:

```
    .thumbnails {
    text-align: center;
}
.thumbnails li {
    width: 150px;
    height: 250px;
    background: red;
    float: none !important; /* to overwrite the default property on the bootstrap stylesheet */
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline; /* ie7 support */
    zoom: 1;
}
```

I noticed it is already horizontally aligned, my problem is to align it vertically. What should I do? Please help thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know its a little late but not sure if this helps - http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-3</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-3</div>

  <!-- Add the extra clearfix for only the required viewport -->
  <div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-3</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-3</div>
</div>
```

Thanks,

Ash.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it with a row or container.

```
<div class="products">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="thumbnails">'
      <li>
        <div>'.$item->ASIN.'</div>
        <div><img src="'.$item->SmallImage->URL.'" alt=""></div>
        <div>'.$item->ItemAttributes->Title.'</div>
        <div>'.$item->ItemAttributes->ProductGroup.'</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to make this better that I've found: manually setting the element height / keeping the element heights consistent, OR the following CSS:

```
  .thumbnails > li {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
  .thumbnails > li:nth-child(3n+4) {
    clear: both;
  }
```

Wrapping this in a container won't fix the problem; it'll just constrain it to a smaller space.

Similar issues:

[vertically aligning thumbnails in bootstrap css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12811403/vertically-aligning-thumbnails-in-bootstrap-css)

[Aligning thumbnails along columns using twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463367/aligning-thumbnails-along-columns-using-twitter-bootstrap)

[twitter bootstrap thumbnails not aligning properly anywhere but Chrome + Windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476503/twitter-bootstrap-thumbnails-not-aligning-properly-anywhere-but-chrome-windows)